# Fine-Uploader: JavaScript error: cannot find template script at ID 'qq-template'!

Tags: javascript, templates, fine-uploader

I'm getting the following error:

```
Uncaught Error: Cannot find template script at ID 'qq-template'!
```

I found this answer: [Uncaught Error: Cannot find template script at ID 'qq-template'!](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19847005/uncaught-error-cannot-find-template-script-at-id-qq-template)
, but it is not helpful for me because I HAVE a template in my html code:

```
<script type="text/template" id="qq-template">
    <div class="qq-uploader-selector qq-uploader span12">
        <div class="qq-upload-drop-area-selector qq-upload-drop-area span12" qq-hide-dropzone>
            <span>****my custom text****</span>
        </div>
        <div class="qq-upload-button-selector qq-upload-button btn btn-success" style="width: auto;">
            <div><i class="icon-upload icon-white"></i>****my custom text****</div>
        </div>
        <span class="qq-drop-processing-selector qq-drop-processing">
            <span>****my custom text****</span>
            <span class="qq-drop-processing-spinner-selector qq-drop-processing-spinner"></span>
        </span>
        <ul class="qq-upload-list-selector qq-upload-list" style="margin-top: 10px; text-align: center;">
            <li>
            <div class="qq-progress-bar-container-selector">
                <div class="qq-progress-bar-selector qq-progress-bar"></div>
            </div>
            <span class="qq-upload-spinner-selector qq-upload-spinner"></span>
            <span class="qq-upload-file-selector qq-upload-file"></span>
            <span class="qq-upload-size-selector qq-upload-size"></span>
            <a class="qq-upload-cancel-selector qq-upload-cancel" href="#">****my custom text****</a>
            <span class="qq-upload-status-text-selector qq-upload-status-text"></span>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</script>
```

And I can successfully get it by calling:

```
document.getElementById('qq-template')
```

I found this template in the official examples and I left it unchanged except for my custom text.

I tried to put this element either inside the <head> and the <body>, but I keep getting the error.

Fine-uploader version is 4.0.3.

What is wrong? What should I do to fix this?

Comment: Are you sure you are executing your script only after DOM has loaded?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Thanks to @Shreyas

The problem was that I put this code:

```
window.onload = createUploader();
```

Instead of this:

```
window.onload = createUploader;
```

'createUploader()' is the function that creates an uploader instance.

This simple mistype was the cause.